# Passing Child class as parameter

Tags: c#, oop

I have a base class

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public DateTime CreateTime { get; set; }
    public string CreateUser { get; set; }
}
```

And few child classes which derive from Base Class

```
public class Child1 : BaseClass
{
}

public class Child2 : BaseClass
{
}
```

For the Client which uses these child classes can I create a method outside these classes which can accept both child class as arguments and change its base class objects?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific (in terms of example code) what you want to achieve? What do you mean by 'changing the base class objects', exactly?

Comment: "Can I create a method"...in the time it took you to create this post, you could have tried to code it yourself.

Comment: I mean can I change the CreateTime and CreateUser of both the ChildClasss(they should be accessible from childclass object )  from one method? It is correct to create a method with baseclass as parameter and pass the child class instances as parameters and change their createtime and createuser members?

Comment: @musical_coder tried creating a method with base class as parameter and passed in child class instances and changed their member values but not sure if this correct and  only way to do it?

Comment: Okay, but in the future, please show us those kind of details of what you've tried so far, when you first create a post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. That is the point of a base class and/or interface:

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public DateTime CreateTime { get; set; }
    public string CreateUser { get; set; }
}

public class Child1 : BaseClass
{
}

public class Child2 : BaseClass
{
}

public static class Test
{
   public static void SetBaseClassValue(BaseClass b)
   {
      b.CreateUser = "John";
   }
}

public static class Program
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      var c1 = new Child1();
      var c2 = new Child2();

      Test.SetBaseClassValue(c1);
      Test.SetBaseClassValue(c2);

      Console.WriteLine(c1.CreateUser);
      Console.WriteLine(c2.CreateUser);
      Console.ReadLine();
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks mate!! Just wasn't sure if this was the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a method that will take both types as parameters like this:

```
public void SomeMethod(BaseClass class)
{
    class.CreateTime = DateTime.Now;
    class.CreateUser = "SomeUser";
}
```

and then call the method like this:

```
public Class1 class1 = new Class1();
public Class2 class2 = new Class2();
SomeMethod(class1);
SomeMethod(class2);
```

Both child classes will inherit the properties from the abstract base class, and can be used as a BaseClass parameter because they inherit from BaseClass.